# Parallels Plesk Unable to open the directory: Access denied

Tags: plesk

I am using Parallels Plesk 12.0.18

The proble is that when i try to open httpdocs  it warn me [Unable to open the directory: Access denied] and i can't open the directory, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

What is the permission and ownership of httpdocs directory. Please update the correct ownership to httpdocs directory and check it again